# Trouble with zip function in for loop; python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, zip

Working in python 2.7.

I have two lists (simplified to make explanation more clear):

```
T = [[1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 5], [3, -1]]
B = [[1], [3], [2], [2]]
```

And three functions.

```
def exit_score(list):
    exit_scores = []
    length = len(list)
    for i in range(0, length):
        score = list[i][2] - list[i][0]
        exit_scores.append(score)
    return exit_scores
```

First I append the corresponding values of B to the corresponding lists in T:

```
def Trans(T, B):
    for t, b in zip(T, B):
        t.extend(b)
    a = exit_score(T)
    b = T
    score_add(b, a)
```

Then, using the previously listed exit_score function. I subtract the the value in the list[2] position from the value in the list[0] position fore each list. I then append those results to another list (exit_scores).

Finally, I want to add the exit_scores (now a), to the original list.

So I use my score_add(b, a) function which is:

```
score_add(team, exit_scores):
    for t, e in zip(team, exit_scores)
        t.extend(e)
    print team
```

If everything were working correctly, I would get an output like this:

```
[[1,0,1,0], [1,0,3,-2], [0,5,2,-2], [3,-1,2,1]]
```

Instead, I get a TypeError telling me that I can't iterate over an integer. But I've tried printing both a and b and both are in list form!

When I change the code to make sure that the exit scores are in a list:

```
def Trans(T, B):
    es = []
    for t, b in zip(T, B):
        t.extend(b)
    es.append(exit_score(T))
    score_add(T, es)
```

The entire exit_scores list (es) is added to the end of the first list of T:

```
[[1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, -1], [1, 0, 3], [0, 5, 2], [3, -1, 2]]
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: You need to re-think all of that code. It's _way_ more complex than it needs to be for a _very_ simple operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This time it's `list.append()`, not `list.extend()`:

```
def score_add(team, exit_scores):
    for t, e in zip(team, exit_scores)
        t.append(e)
    print team
```

`B` was a list of lists, while `exit_scores` is a list of integers.

**Edit**: Here is a cleaned-up version of the whole code:

```
for t, b in zip(T, B):
    t.extend(b)
    t.append(t[2] - t[0])
```

Comment: Right you are. Do you know I good resource where I can learn about these commands. Obviously, this area is a bit of a weakness...

Comment: @BurtonGuster: I'd start with some Python tutorial.  The offficial tutorial is quite good, and I also like [How to Think Like a Computer Scientist](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/).

Answer (score 0):

I'll bite:

```
map(lambda x, y: x + y + [x[0] - y[0]], T, B)
```

Yielding:

```
[[1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 3, -2], [0, 5, 2, -2], [3, -1, 2, 1]]
```

Also, it can be done in a list comprehension:

```
[x+y+[x[0]-y[0]] for x, y in zip(T, B)]
```

Comment: You've reproduced the result the OP didn't want.